# How to remap Company's select next and select previous keys?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, company-mode, tooltip

I don't like the default <kbd>M-n</kbd> and <kbd>M-p</kbd> keys for `company-select-next` and `company-select-previous` so I was wondering if it's possible to remap those to <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> without affecting the mappings when company's tooltip is not active.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Modify `company-active-map` accordingly:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-n") nil)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-p") nil)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous))
```

Comment: Do you know why do I get `Symbol's value as variable is void: company-active-map` after modifying `company-active-map`, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: `company-active-map` is not defined before company is loaded obviously.  You need to evaluate these commands **after** company was loaded, e.g. with `with-eval-after-load`.  I updated my answer accordingly.