# Arrow and M-n M-p don't work with company mode in terminal when ESC aborts completion

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, company-mode, terminal-emacs

In a terminal window, I'm finding that company-mode completion doesn't work, whereas it does work in a graphical window. For example a down arrow inserts the text `OB` and M-n simply inserts `n`.

As a workaround, I've followed [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2990/5426) to use C-n and C-p like so

```
(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous))
```

but I'd prefer to use the same keys whether I'm running graphically or via ssh.

This used to work, and I've upgraded my configuration files and installed a lot more packages recently, but even reducing my initialization file down to just the company mode code didn't fix the problem.

Edit: I've isolated the problem down to this line of code that I copied from the [graphene](https://github.com/rdallasgray/graphene/blob/master/graphene-editing.el) package that redefines ESC to abort the completion.

```
 (define-key company-active-map (kbd "ESC") 'company-abort)
```

I can see how this might stop M-n and M-p working because `ESC` has got something to do with the Alt key in emacs. I can workaround the problem in a terminal using

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (with-eval-after-load 'company
      (define-key company-active-map (kbd "ESC") 'company-abort)))
```

which means that single ESC aborts completion in a graphical frame, and triple ESC aborts in a terminal.

However is it still be possible for the arrow keys to work with single ESC? My preference is to use arrow keys and single escape if possible.

Comment: The problem here is that ESC sends `C-[`, M-f sends `C-[ f` and the down arrow sends `C-[ [1;3B`. As you can see, ESC is a prefix of the codes sent by both all Meta keys and the arrow keys, so you can't do it; not without hacks like using timers at any rate. Why not get used to `C-g` for quitting? It's the Emacs standard, and it's arguably easier to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fallen victim to the limitations of terminal control sequences.

- <kbd><escape></kbd> actually sends <kbd>**C-[**</kbd>
- <kbd>M-f</kbd> actually sends <kbd>**C-[**</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>
- <kbd><up></kbd> actually sends <kbd>**C-[**</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Becuase <kbd><escape></kbd> is a prefix of <kbd>M-f</kbd>, you can't really bind it. This is not entirely true. You can still bind it using timers that determine whether <kbd><escape></kbd> is a command or a prefix, but I don't recommend using it.

Long term, <kbd>C-g</kbd> is the better solution. It's standardized and should work everywhere in Emacs.

Comment: Is there a way of adding a small delay to see if the control sequence is longer than C-[ ?