# Remap Company's select next and select previous keys, with evil-mode?

Tags: evil, company-mode

When `company-mode` pops up suggestions, I want to use `C-n` and `C-p` to select the next or the previous options, instead of `M-n` and `M-p`.

Having found [the general answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-to-remap-companys-select-next-and-select-previous-keys/2990#2990?newreg=54bac8d8440043aab447e18c899d32be) on this site, I was happy to try it out, but it turns out that doesn't work for me.  I suspect this is because I have Evil mode enabled.

When I'm in evil-insert-mode, pressing `C-h k C-n` tells me:

```
C-n runs the command evil-next-line (found in evil-insert-state-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to C-n.

(evil-next-line &optional COUNT)

Move the cursor COUNT lines down.
```

Is there any way I can shadow this correctly in `company-active-map`?

For completeness, my configuration is:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'company
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-n") nil)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "M-p") nil)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next)
  (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous))
```

Comment: Try this one, works with my setup: `(with-eval-after-load 'company (with-eval-after-load 'evil (evil-define-key nil company-active-map (kbd "C-s") #'company-select-next)))`

Comment: hmm, yours actually works as well :-) Are you using evil-collection? Maybe the after 'evil is needed as this might overwrite it globally. Or as it tells you about insert state map: `(evil-define-key 'insert company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I understood why, but thanks to @Hubisan's comment I was able to get it to work.  I have tried many permutations, but this is the only one that seems to actually work:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
  (with-eval-after-load 'company
    (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-n") nil)
    (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-p") nil)
    (evil-define-key nil company-active-map (kbd "C-n") #'company-select-next)
    (evil-define-key nil company-active-map (kbd "C-p") #'company-select-previous)))
```